# Errores en la instalacion de phpmyadmin en Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: phpmyadmin, ubuntu, instalacion

Estoy tratando de instalar phpmyadmin en Ubuntu 20.04

Realice la instalacion con:

1. sudo apt-get install apache2
2. sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
3. sudo mysql -u root -p
4. (cambie contraseña)
5. sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql
6. sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
7. (elegi apache2 y puse la misma contraseña del mysql)

Me muestra varios errores que, si bien al ignorarlos me deja iniciar sesion, una vez adentro no me deja realizar ninguna accion:

> Deprecation Notice in ./libraries/classes/Url.php#221
> http_build_query(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($numeric_prefix) of
> type string is deprecated
>
> Backtrace
>
> ./libraries/classes/Url.php#221: http_build_query( array, NULL, string
> '&', ) ./libraries/classes/Header.php#231:
> PhpMyAdmin\Url::getCommonRaw() ./libraries/classes/Header.php#282:
> PhpMyAdmin\Header->getJsParams() ./libraries/classes/Header.php#214:
> PhpMyAdmin\Header->getJsParamsCode()
> ./libraries/classes/Header.php#142:
> PhpMyAdmin\Header->_addDefaultScripts()
> ./libraries/classes/Response.php#100: PhpMyAdmin\Header->__construct()
> ./libraries/classes/Response.php#134:
> PhpMyAdmin\Response->__construct()
> ./libraries/classes/Plugins/Auth/AuthenticationCookie.php#87:
> PhpMyAdmin\Response::getInstance()
> ./libraries/classes/Plugins/AuthenticationPlugin.php#247:
> PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\Auth\AuthenticationCookie->showLoginForm()
> ./libraries/common.inc.php#353:
> PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin->authenticate()
> ./index.php#27: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)

> Deprecation Notice in ./../../php/Twig/Loader/FilesystemLoader.php#40
> realpath(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($path) of type string is
> deprecated
>
> Backtrace
>
> FilesystemLoader.php#40: realpath(NULL)
> ./libraries/classes/Template.php#61:
> Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader->__construct(string 'templates/')
> ./libraries/classes/Template.php#102:
> PhpMyAdmin\Template->__construct(string 'login/header')
> ./libraries/classes/Plugins/Auth/AuthenticationCookie.php#111:
> PhpMyAdmin\Template::get(string 'login/header')
> ./libraries/classes/Plugins/AuthenticationPlugin.php#247:
> PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\Auth\AuthenticationCookie->showLoginForm()
> ./libraries/common.inc.php#353:
> PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin->authenticate()
> ./index.php#27: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)

> Deprecation Notice in ./libraries/classes/Url.php#221
> http_build_query(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($numeric_prefix) of
> type string is deprecated
>
> Backtrace
>
> ./libraries/classes/Url.php#221: http_build_query( array, NULL, string
> '&', ) ./libraries/classes/Url.php#169: PhpMyAdmin\Url::getCommonRaw(
> array, string '?', ) ./libraries/classes/Core.php#749:
> PhpMyAdmin\Url::getCommon(array)
> ./../../../../../../var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp/twig/78/781a2fcd26f8d7222e0c3677150755f3a3734955aa2fa6c8121c9aec91dd39ba.php#40:
> PhpMyAdmin\Core::linkURL(string 'https://www.phpmyadmin.net/')
> Template.php#407:
> __TwigTemplate_53b077702a8825b8da118f9528dcec7bbf3200d51675d6d128fea704a639cdf4->doDisplay(
> array, array, ) Template.php#380:
> Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling( array, array, )
> Template.php#392: Twig\Template->display(array)
> TemplateWrapper.php#45: Twig\Template->render( array, array, )
> ./libraries/classes/Template.php#133:
> Twig\TemplateWrapper->render(array)
> ./libraries/classes/Plugins/Auth/AuthenticationCookie.php#111:
> PhpMyAdmin\Template->render(array)
> ./libraries/classes/Plugins/AuthenticationPlugin.php#247:
> PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\Auth\AuthenticationCookie->showLoginForm()
> ./libraries/common.inc.php#353:
> PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin->authenticate()
> ./index.php#27: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)

> Deprecation Notice in ./../../php/Twig/Node/Node.php#161 Return type
> of Twig\Node\Node::count() should either be compatible with
> Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute
> should be used to temporarily suppress the notice
>
> Backtrace
>
> autoload.php#369: require(./../../php/Twig/Node/Node.php)
> {closure}(string 'Twig\Node\Node') TwigFilter.php#150:
> class_exists(string 'Twig\Node\Node') autoload.php#369:
> require(./../../php/Twig/TwigFilter.php) CoreExtension.php#214:
> {closure}(string 'Twig\TwigFilter') ExtensionSet.php#433:
> Twig\Extension\CoreExtension->getFilters() ExtensionSet.php#423:
> Twig\ExtensionSet->initExtension() ExtensionSet.php#184:
> Twig\ExtensionSet->initExtensions() Environment.php#871:
> Twig\ExtensionSet->getFunction(string 'Message_error')
> ./../../../../../../var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp/twig/78/781a2fcd26f8d7222e0c3677150755f3a3734955aa2fa6c8121c9aec91dd39ba.php#55:
> Twig\Environment->getFunction(string 'Message_error')
> Template.php#407:
> __TwigTemplate_53b077702a8825b8da118f9528dcec7bbf3200d51675d6d128fea704a639cdf4->doDisplay(
> array, array, ) Template.php#380:
> Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling( array, array, )
> Template.php#392: Twig\Template->display(array)
> TemplateWrapper.php#45: Twig\Template->render( array, array, )
> ./libraries/classes/Template.php#133:
> Twig\TemplateWrapper->render(array)
> ./libraries/classes/Plugins/Auth/AuthenticationCookie.php#111:
> PhpMyAdmin\Template->render(array)
> ./libraries/classes/Plugins/AuthenticationPlugin.php#247:
> PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\Auth\AuthenticationCookie->showLoginForm()
> ./libraries/common.inc.php#353:
> PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin->authenticate()
> ./index.php#27: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)

> Deprecation Notice in ./../../php/Twig/Node/Node.php#166 Return type
> of Twig\Node\Node::getIterator() should either be compatible with
> IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice
>
> Backtrace
>
> autoload.php#369: require(./../../php/Twig/Node/Node.php)
> {closure}(string 'Twig\Node\Node') TwigFilter.php#150:
> class_exists(string 'Twig\Node\Node') autoload.php#369:
> require(./../../php/Twig/TwigFilter.php) CoreExtension.php#214:
> {closure}(string 'Twig\TwigFilter') ExtensionSet.php#433:
> Twig\Extension\CoreExtension->getFilters() ExtensionSet.php#423:
> Twig\ExtensionSet->initExtension() ExtensionSet.php#184:
> Twig\ExtensionSet->initExtensions() Environment.php#871:
> Twig\ExtensionSet->getFunction(string 'Message_error')
> ./../../../../../../var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp/twig/78/781a2fcd26f8d7222e0c3677150755f3a3734955aa2fa6c8121c9aec91dd39ba.php#55:
> Twig\Environment->getFunction(string 'Message_error')
> Template.php#407:
> __TwigTemplate_53b077702a8825b8da118f9528dcec7bbf3200d51675d6d128fea704a639cdf4->doDisplay(
> array, array, ) Template.php#380:
> Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling( array, array, )
> Template.php#392: Twig\Template->display(array)
> TemplateWrapper.php#45: Twig\Template->render( array, array, )
> ./libraries/classes/Template.php#133:
> Twig\TemplateWrapper->render(array)
> ./libraries/classes/Plugins/Auth/AuthenticationCookie.php#111:
> PhpMyAdmin\Template->render(array)
> ./libraries/classes/Plugins/AuthenticationPlugin.php#247:
> PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\Auth\AuthenticationCookie->showLoginForm()
> ./libraries/common.inc.php#353:
> PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin->authenticate()
> ./index.php#27: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)

Comment: ¿Revisaste [esta issue](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/17225) en el repositorio de PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: gracias, funciono

Comment: No olvides ponerlo como respuesta (en base a [answer]) y [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer).